# Hackerrank Game of Two Stacks

Tags: java, stack

I cannot see what's wrong with the following code, I couldn't pass the test cases on Hackerrank with my solution, could you give me an example as to where my code is failing? Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Here is the problem statement: 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/game-of-two-stacks/problem

Here is the solution I proposed :

```
   static int twoStacks(int x, int[] a, int[] b) {

        Stack<Integer> stack1 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> stack2 = new Stack<>();

        for(int i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            stack1.push(a[i]);
        }

        for(int i=b.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            stack2.push(b[i]);
        }

        int counter = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int top1, top2;

        while(sum<=x) {
            top1 = stack1.peek();
            top2 = stack2.peek();

            if(top1<=top2) {
                sum+=top1;
                stack1.pop();
            } else if (top2< top1) {
                sum+=top2;
                stack2.pop();
            }

            if(sum<=x) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: Explain what you expect and what you get (at very least).

Comment: Always choosing the smallest element between the 2 stacks won't give you the most optimized solution, for example with x = 6, stack1 = [3,3,3], stack2 = [4,1,1]. The right answer would pick the 3 elements of stack2, while your algorithm would pick the first 2 elements of stack1.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is wrong because your `while` loop won't terminate if `sum` never becomes greater than `x` or equal to it. Your `counter` would keep on increasing forever.

You need to add a `break` when both the stacks have become empty.

```
if(stack1.empty() && stack2.empty())
   break;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, you are right; unfortunately that doesn't help to pass the 13 test cases from hackerrank, I still pass only 2 out of 13 cases.

Comment: @BrunoMo Yep, here's another one. Assume the case when *only one* of the two stacks becomes empty. When you peek an empty stack it would throw an `EmptyStackException`. You need to stop peeking from both the stacks and comparing their values when one of the stacks has gone empty. Just keep popping from the alternate stack.